# Automated SVN commit when the code runs successfully

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ankhsvn

I am working on a team project and keep running into issues of people not committing to the SVN when the project builds AND runs successfully. Is there any way of, on safe-exit (application closes in the desired way), a script is run to then call a commit to SVN for the current state of the project?

We are using Visual Studio 2010/2012 with the AnkhSVN plugin with the code is written in C# and XNA.

Comment: Do you really ALWAYS want to commit when the program exits successfully? Perhaps someone commented out a chunk of code to test something - the more standard approach is to require to the code to compile and run before a checkin is allowed. This is often done by having a build server checkout the proposed commit, build it, run it and then allow/reject the checkin. TFS calls these gated checkins, I'm unsure aboutthe SVN equivalent but you could probably automate it through some custom [hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html)(see hook scripts)

Comment: Obviously I don't know what your _exact_ circumstances or reasons are for wanting this... but I have a hard time coming up with a good reason _why_ any developer would _want_ to automatically commit just after build/run. Do you even have it prompt for a commit message about the changes? Do you have developers inspect and clean their code to remove unnecessary/temporary content before committing? Sounds more like a process issue between you and your developers.

Comment: There is no reason to commit code just because the project builds and exits without errors. There may be a ton of bugs elsewhere in the application and a commit should only be done when changes are fully tested. Consider tackling this problem closer to the root cause: your team does not behave as it should. You might want to go read about automated build servers.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but you could set up a post-build event under the project's properties that would commit after an successful build.